# RegExp to find and replace all the spaces between two separate delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all the white space between two separate delimiters and replace to effectively remove it.

For instance:

```
{First Value} where {Second Available Value} is greater than {Value}
```

I want the string to become:

```
{FirstValue} where {SecondAvailableValue} is greater than {Value}
```

I have little experience in regexp but this what I tried on a regex builder:

```
/{([^}]*)}/g
```

This however matches the sub strings (words in between the curl braces) including the delimiter

How can I match just the spaces inside the curly braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try doing a regex replace with a callback function, targeting the following pattern:

```
\{.*?\}
```

That is, we will try to match every term contained in curly braces.  This callback function can then remove all spaces.

```js
var input = "{First Value} where {Second Available Value} is greater than {Value}";
console.log(input);
input = input.replace(/\{.*?\}/g, function(match, contents, offset, input_string) {
    return match.replace(/ /g, '');
});

console.log(input);
```